# Deciphering an Asian Bladder Pressure Tank + Pump

Tags: plumbing, pump

I have a bladder pressure tank + pump combo, and I'm trying to figure it out. It came with no manual, was bought in Cambodia, and is being used on the second floor of a home using city water (which is low pressure). It supplies an LPG water heater, which requires better flow. I want to make sure that the bladder pressure tank is properly charged, but I have no clue to know what the pressure ranges are to make sure it doesn't cycle (it currently cycles a lot).

**Does this label contain that information? How do I interpret this label? If this information isn't provided, what can I do?**

[image: Lucky Star LS0.5 Auto]

The unit looks like this:

[image: The Unit]

Comment: Italy is the name of a city in China

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find it in a search and the soft letter Y is rarely used in Chinese:English translation.

Comment: lol. Maybe that's their hopeful target market, and somehow, someway, it ended up here :)

Comment: Pompatipo.fase 1 roughly [translates](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=pompa%20tipo%20fase) to *single phase type pump* in Italian.

Comment: Nice. Maybe Italy was the real target after all...

Comment: Perhaps it was "bought off the back of a lorry" in Cambodia or was one that failed testing and was in the pile for re-work...

Comment: lol, I wouldn't be surprised with either. Up north (Laos) they had a really nice one for just a bit more, but the timing wasn't right for us to get it. It actually seems to run fine, but I think it may need some more air and adjustment to keep it from wearing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That label describes the motor specifications, not the pressure tank.
Single Phase, 220 Volt 50 hertz, 1/2 horsepower (.5 HP), 2850 Revolutions Per Minute (RPM), Continuous Service (SERV C), Suction 9 (possibly BARS).

I'm not sure what the other abbreviations are, but they could be related to the pressure tank.

Most pressure tanks work based on what you want your target pressure to be.

In english, my large 80 gallon pressure tank keeps my household water pressure around 60PSI (~4 BARS). In most cases, the bladder in this tank would probably be set to a similar pressure (size of the tank shouldn't matter, pressure is pressure).

Your tank looks a little small for a water heater supplying a shower or something using a similar volume, so you can expect it to cycle more often, and in fact, because of the CONTINUOUS rating, it's probably designed that way for on-demand pressure.